# 権限解放に必要な信用度が本家SOと異なる

Tags: 討議

日本語版stackoverflowと本家stackoverflowでは、各権限(privileges)の解放に必要とされる信用度(reputation)が、意図的に異なる値に設定されているのでしょうか？

- 本家：https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges
- 日本語版：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

日本語版は全般的に少ない信用度で権限解放されるようですが、これはベータ版であることを考慮した意図的な設定ですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そうです。パブリックベーターまでは権限に必要な信用度が抑えています。パブリックベーターになる時、変わります。